# How can i model this data

Tags: database-design, erd

A customer can make a reservation for an accommodation, the accommodation can be in a resort or elsewhere.

So i would say that a resort can have different types of accommodations, ie. Chalets, apartments bungalows, caravans, lodges, hotels, etc...

and if a customer wants to make a reservation for these types of accommodation but not in a resort.

How would i model it?

- ps. lets assume that elsewhere* means a hotel outside the resort

ERD Diagram-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9W6d.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is "resort" a special type of entity? If not then you could model this as:

```
Customer
--------
  CustomerID - unique primary key
  Name - text
  (other customer fields)

Accomodation
------------
  AccomodationID - unique primary key
  LocationID - foreign key to "where" the accomodation is
  AccomodationTypeID - foreign key to types of accomodations
  (other stuff such as "# bathrooms", "# beds...")

Location
--------
  LocationID - unique primiary key
  LocationTypeID - foreign key to location type
  (other fields)

Reservasions
------------
  ReservationID - unique primary key
  CustomerID - foreign key to customer
  AccomodationID - foreign key to accomodation
  StartDate
  EndDate
  (any other fields you need)

LocationTypes
-------------
  LocationTypeID
  Description (such as "Resort", "campground",...)

AccomodationTypes
-----------------
  AccomodationTypeID
  Description (such as "Lean-to", "chalet", "motel",...)
```

Comment: What do you mean by special

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos: You say "the accommodation can be in a resort or elsewhere". Does this mean that you want to treat Resorts differently than whatever would be considered "elsewhere", do you want to have exactly two options: "Resort" and "Elsewhere", or was "Resort" just one of many possible examples for where an accomodation could be?

Comment: i want to assume that elsewhere means a hotel not in the resort. so a customer can either book resort based accommodation or a room hotel, however a resort can also have hotels in them. im going to model it

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos: If I understand you correctly, this above model would still work: You will only need two rows in LocationTypes; one for "Resort" one for "Off-resort". If you want to simplify the model, you could remove LocationTypes and then replace Location.LocationTypeID with a simple "Is a Resort?" indicator field.

Comment: If i use hotel as an accommodation type, it is very unlikely that a customer will book many hotels, however a customer can book a whole chalet, bungalow. how can i deal with this, thats if a customer decides to book a room in a hotel

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos: It's *possible* a customer will want to book a hotel: a small hotel and a large corporate event *can* make it happen. But in general, I would try to enforce that sort of logic in the application, not in the database. Also, you might want to use "HotelRoom" as the accomodation type, and "Hotel" as the location type.